# How to invoke custom code snippets for Rmarkdown documents in RStudio

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio

There are few pre-defined snippets one can use in RStudio for Rmarkdown documents. I define my own snippets via Global Options > Code > Edit snippets > Markdown. But it doesn't work. If I type `r` and press Shift+Tab a pre-defined snippet is inserted. But when I want to insert my own snippet it doesn't work. For example, this is my snippet I'd like to have:

```
snippet custy
  :::{custom-style="${1:style}"}
  ${0}
  :::
```

I thought when I type `custy` and press Shift+Tab the snippet will be inserted into my document, but it doesn't. Should the snippet be defined differently?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your snipped and it worked well.
Make sure you are on the "Markdown" tab. Plus, are indentations OK? the snippet should be colored blue.